# How to use apply with currying?

Tags: javascript, currying

I have code that is using currying to get the average on an array that results from concatenating two arrays: an n size array and an m size array.

```
var avg = function(...n){ 
  let tot=0;
  for(let i=0; i<n.length; i++){
    tot += n[i];
  }
  return tot/n.length;
};

var spiceUp = function(fn, ...n){
  return function(...m){
    return fn.apply(this, n.concat(m));
  }
};

var doAvg = spiceUp(avg, 1,2,3);
console.log(doAvg(4,5,6));
```

In this line `return fn.apply(this, n.concat(m));`, I don't understand why do we need to use `apply`. What is the object we are binding with the average function and why does just normal calling (`return fn(n.concat(m));`) not work?

Comment: it will work great with just `return fn(n.concat(m));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example, `this` is not that important. It would also work if instead of this you would pass an empty object instead. It's just an example on how to use apply.

What you need to focus is on the second parameter `n.concat(m)`. They key concept here is that passing an array as a second argument you are calling that function (`fn`) passing each value in the array as an argument.

About your second question: no, it won't work because `fn` expects several arguments (one per value to calculate the average) while by doing `return fn(n.concat(m));` you are just passing one argument, an array containing all values

Maybe you would understand it better with a simpler example:

```
function sum3params(a,b,c){
    return a+b+c;
}

console.log(sum3params([3,4,2])) // won't work
console.log(sum3params.apply(this, [3,4,2])) // will work ('this' is not important here)
```

Comment: how does `apply` converts the n.concat(m) to be group of values instead of an array ?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed it just does. `apply` is a built-in function, it can do anything the platform is capable of. I am not aware of a way to achieve this behavior without recourse to the underlying runtime. You might as well ask why `var foo = 3` binds the value 3 to the name 'foo' so you can re-use it. As far as JavaScript is concerned, its magic.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, it does not. But consider the following:

```
var foo = {
  bar: 3
};

var addBar = function(a, b) { return a + b + this.bar };
foo.add3AndBar = spiceUp(addBar, 3);
foo.add3AndBar(1); // 7
```

Using `apply` means that your `spiceUp` function can be applied to methods as well as normal functions. For more likely example, consider partially applying when defining a method on a prototype:

```
const ENV = "linux";
DoesSomePlatformSpecificStuff.prototype.getPath = spiceUp(ENV);
```

`apply` also will spread the gathered array of arguments back out into positional arguments which can also be done like so:

```
return fn(...n.concat(m));
```

Which can be simplified as

```
return fn(...n, ...m);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
return fn.apply(undefined, n.concat(m));
```